# How to handle failed jenkins build jobs with automated python script

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote a python script to kick off build jobs for all of our microservices. I am doing some testing and want to ensure I handle a job that occurs an error and fails somewhere in the deploy.jenkins file.

I basically just created another pipeline job for this deployment build script, call it manually from jenkins then it checks out from github, builds my docker container, then kicks off all the microservices that I want to deploy.

So for now to test, I added a `sh "exit 1"` in on of the microservices to fail one of the jobs and when it fails, it also fails my whole deploy job script. The other microservices continue to build, but my script also polls/tracks each job after they are kicked off until they are complete, with a goal in the future to write a teams webhook with status, so I'm missing all this once the script exits because of one failed build.

What's the best way to handle a failed job without terminating my deployment script so it doesn't exit and can continue polling the other build jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what i have understand, this is what you want to achieve:

I have a master pipeline job say `stackoverflow` and there are three downstream pipeline jobs `test1`, `test2` and `test3` (which in case are your microservices job)

Let us fail the job `test1` by adding `sh "exit 1"` and capture it in master pipeline but rest all `test2` and `test3` should run irrespective of the failed `test1` job.

Here is the declarative pipeline code for the **master pipeline job**:

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('simple stage') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('test1 job') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                build propagate: true, job: 'test1'
            }
          }
        }
        stage('test2 job') {
            steps {
                build propagate: true, job: 'test2'
            }
        }
        stage('test3 job') {
            steps {
                build propagate: true, job: 'test3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pipeline code of other downstream jobs:

1. **test1 pipeline job**

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 1'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

2. **test2 pipeline job**

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

3. **test3 pipeline job**

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

When we run the **master pipeline job**, below is the result what we get:

[image]

**Console Output**

[image]